# Import Error: cannot import name 'get_jwt_header_name'

Tags: python

Python import system is really confusing me. The same code use to start and work well, but suddenly I've started to get this message. Can anyone help me understand why am I receiving this error? Here is the stack

```
(.venv) aks:src$ python fakeauth.py 
INFO:root:Logging to stderr
Trying to load environment variables from .env file...
2017-12-20 20:11:23,566 [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] INFO in main._mainWrapper:71: Starting main.main()...
2017-12-20 20:11:23,566 [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] INFO in main.main:30: Fakeauth is initializing...
2017-12-20 20:11:23,567 [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] INFO in main.main:57: Swagger response validation is ENABLED. This can degrade performance.
2017-12-20 20:11:23,721 [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR in api._handle_add_operation_error:261: Failed to add operation for GET /fakeauth/ping
2017-12-20 20:11:23,722 [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR in main.main:87: Error in Fakeauth!
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/api.py", line 237, in add_paths
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     self.add_operation(method, path, endpoint, path_parameters)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/api.py", line 189, in add_operation
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     resolver=self.resolver)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/operation.py", line 210, in __init__
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     resolution = resolver.resolve(self)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 39, in resolve
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     return Resolution(self.resolve_function_from_operation_id(operation_id), operation_id)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 65, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     raise ResolverError(msg, sys.exc_info())
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR: connexion.exceptions.ResolverError: <ResolverError: Cannot resolve operationId "common.api.ping.ping"!>
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR: 
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR: During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR: 
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/myapp/fakeauth/src/main.py", line 59, in main
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     'fakeauth.yaml', strict_validation=True, validate_responses=responseValidation)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/app.py", line 168, in add_api
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     validator_map=self.validator_map)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/api.py", line 153, in __init__
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     self.add_paths()
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/api.py", line 248, in add_paths
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     self._handle_add_operation_error(path, method, exc_info)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/api.py", line 262, in _handle_add_operation_error
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     six.reraise(*exc_info)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 686, in reraise
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     raise value
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/resolver.py", line 62, in resolve_function_from_operation_id
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     return self.function_resolver(operation_id)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/utils.py", line 119, in get_function_from_name
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     raise last_import_error
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/connexion/utils.py", line 107, in get_function_from_name
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/.pyenv/versions/3.6.3/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/myapp/fakeauth/src/common/api/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     from common.api import auth
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:   File "/home/aks/myapp/fakeauth/src/common/api/auth.py", line 13, in <module>
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR:     from flask_jwt_extended.config import get_jwt_header_name
... [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] ERROR: ImportError: cannot import name 'get_jwt_header_name'
2017-12-20 20:11:23,723 [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] INFO in main.main:89: Fakeauth has terminated.
2017-12-20 20:11:23,723 [18717/#7fb24c1db6d0] INFO in main._mainWrapper:76: main.main() finished.
```

Any idea why this might be happening? Do you need any other information for this?

Comment: what is "connexion" ???

Comment: It is Open API(Swagger) implementation on top of flask
http://connexion.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I cleaned by virtual env and created it again and it fixes the issue. Still not sure what was wrong.